# How do I get Jxls to generate multiple collections

Tags: java, loops, collections, nested, jxls

here is the problem I am faced with: Nested Collections.

I have an ArrayList (the top level collection) of class . Within each **Subject** I have another ArrayList of type **Group**. The finally I have within each group an ArrayList of **Students**.

I am trying to get the format of my excel file to look like this.

```
**SUBJECT 1**
GROUP 1
 Students

GROUP 2
 Students

**SUBJECT 2**
```

So I'm trying to nest these collections. The trouble is that My final excel file doesn't seem to show all of the data. And I know why. At my top level collection: **Subjects** I have the code:

`${data.subjects.groups.letter}//:4`

The //:4 at the end deceives it because there are going to be multiple groups.
Please please please please, how can I nest multiple collections please?

Comment: Any help full remarks are accepted...anything please. I am at the final stage of my project. I'm desperate for help now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<jx:forEach items="${data.subjects}" var="subject">
  ${subject.name}
  <jx:forEach items="${subject}" var="group">
    ${group.name}
    <jx:forEach items="${group}" var="student">
      ${student.name}
    </jx:forEach>
  </jx:forEach>
</jx:forEach>
```

each in different cells

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the answer did not work for me. What worked for me is something like this with each line in different cells

```
<jx:forEach items="${data.subjects}" var="subject">
    ${subject.name}
    <jx:forEach items="${subject.groups}" var="group">
        ${group.name}
        <jx:forEach items="${group.students}" var="student">
            ${student.name}
        </jx:forEach>
    </jx:forEach>
</jx:forEach>
```